# How to bound above $| \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n} +n}-\frac{1}{2} |$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find and Justify $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$
>   $$S_n = \sqrt{n^2+n} - n = $$

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n^2+n} - n
 = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n} +n}
 = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/n} + 1} = 1/2$$

$S_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ if for every $\epsilon>0 $ there is an integer $N$ s. t. 
$$|S_n-\frac{1}{2}| <\epsilon,n\geq N$$

Considering 
$$|S_n-\frac{1}{2}| = \left| \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n} +n}-\frac{1}{2} \right|= \left|\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2+n}}{2\sqrt{n^2+n}+2n} \right|
\leq   \left|\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2+n}}{2n+2n} \right|
$$
$$ \leq 
\left|\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2+n}}{4n} \right| \leq
\left|\frac{1 -\sqrt{1+1/n}}{4}\right| \leq 
\frac{\sqrt{1/n}}{4} \leq \epsilon$$

let $N$ be such that 
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1/N}}{4} \leq \epsilon => \frac{1}{16 \epsilon^2}<N$$

It follows  for any $\epsilon>0$, if $n \geq N > \frac{1}{16 \epsilon^2}$, then 
$$|S_n-\frac{1}{2}| <\epsilon$$

I am a bit uncertain if it is the right way to proceed particularly with the bound of $N$ in relation to $\epsilon$. Is my method to bound $N$ correct?

Much appreciated for your input.

Comment: You're better off using the 'reduced' form $(1+\sqrt{1+n^{-1}})^{-1}$ to start your calculations. As to how to bound it: note that $1+\frac12\cdot\frac1n\leq \sqrt{1+\frac1n}\leq 1+\frac1n$ - can you see why? That should be enough to get good enough bounds for an $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ approach...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thx for the input . I tried different possibilities. I do not see why $$ 1+ \frac{1}{2n} \leq \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\leq 1+ \frac{1}{n}$$. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: $1<\sqrt {1+1/n}\;<1+1/2n.$ Therefore $\frac {1}{2}>$ $\frac {1}{1+\sqrt {1+1/n}}>$ $\frac {1}{1+(1+1/2n)}=$ $\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1/2n}{4+1/n}>$ $\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1/2n}{4n}=$ $\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1}{8n}$....... We have $\sqrt {1+1/n}\;<1+1/2n$  for $n>0$ because $(1+1/n)<(1+1/2n)^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Your method of proof for me it is correct.

Now the bound of $N$ you need   is $$N=[\frac{1}{16 \epsilon^2}]+1$$

This $N$ is the least natural number with the property:

$$  \frac{\sqrt{1/n}}{4} < \epsilon, \forall n\geqslant N $$

As for answering the comment below,you proved that $N> \frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}$.

We use the double inequality $[x]\leqslant x \leqslant [x]+1$ where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

Thus we have $[\frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}] \leqslant \frac{1}{16\epsilon^2} \leqslant [\frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}]+1$

You see now that the the least positive natural number greater than $\frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}$ is $N=[\frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}]+1$

Thus whenever $n \geqslant N$ we have that desired inequality for the limit.

Comment: thx for the input. Could you elaborate on $N=\frac{1}{16e^2) +1$  why adding one?

Comment: @rei see my edits in the answer..